# where are the properties of Custom object in app insights

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, ilogger

i have a custom object like this.

```
 public class Propertey
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class MonitoringEvent 
{
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public string Service { get; set; }
    public string Fuction { get; set; }
    public string CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public List<Propertey> Properties { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

and this object gets populated from outside the system and in my function app i am trying to log it in App Insights.

```
     [FunctionName("EventMonitoring")]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(
            "cta-event-monitoring",
            "monitoring",
            Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString",
            IsSessionsEnabled = false)]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            MonitoringEvent me = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MonitoringEvent>(mySbMsg);
           
            log.LogInformation("MonitoringEvent", me);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            log.LogError("MonitoringEventError",ex);
        }
    }
```

when i see App insights i cant see properties like "AppName" "Service" etc in app insights. where can i find them ? later i want to be able to query on them as well. but all i see in app insights is something like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to log using a [log message template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#log-message-template). The message template can contain placeholders for which arguments are provided. Use names for the placeholders. In your case that means you need to add a named template position

`log.LogInformation("MonitoringEvent {Event}", me);`

This will create a custom property "Event" in the trace of application insights.

In your current code you do not provide a placeholder so the argument cannot be put somewhere and is ignored.

Also, do mind that application insights will probably use `.ToString()` on any `object` arguments so your best bet will be to just use `mySbMsg` as the argument.

Comment: i can see json string for the object i am sending in. but is there a way to query upon it ? like for example my object has a List<Proeprty> can i query on it within App insights ? 
something like to get all the traces where key = something

Comment: Yes that is possible, you might try one of [these results](https://www.google.com/search?q=kusto+query+parse+json+array&sxsrf=ALeKk02dRz4N0JS9XZKQUrd6Izq5dX2Fwg%3A1621975854081&ei=LmOtYJKzBI2sUt3licAN&oq=kusto+query+parse+json+array&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBwgjELADECcyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsANQAFgAYIYZaAFwAngAgAE9iAE9kgEBMZgBAKoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQnAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiSgvf02uXwAhUNlhQKHd1yAtgQ4dUDCA4&uact=5). If you run into trouble best ask a new question as it is unrelated to this one.

Comment: what about when you need to log a json file?

Comment: @Emil I would probably use a `TelemetryClient` directly and use `TrackTrace` to do that. But be aware there are limitations regarding the size of properties so if the file are large I would store them in a storage account and log only the name of the blob in app insigths.